# Restart streaming query without stopping application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Im trying to restart streaming query in spark using below code inplace of query.awaitTermination(),below code will be inside an infinite loop and looks for trigger to restart query and then executes below code.Basically im trying to refresh cached df.

```
 query.processAllavaialble()
    query.stop()
   //oldDF is a cached Dataframe created from GlobalTempView which is of size 150GB.
          oldDF.unpersist()
    val inputDf: DataFrame = readFile(spec, sparkSession) //read file from S3
    or anyother source
    val recreateddf = inputDf.persist()
    //Start the query// here should i start query again by invoking readStream ?
```

But when i looked into spark documentation it says

```
void processAllAvailable() ///documentation says This method is intended for testing/// Blocks until all available data in the source has been processed and committed to the sink. This method is intended for testing. Note that in the case of continually arriving data, this method may block forever. Additionally, this method is only guaranteed to block until data that has been synchronously appended data to a Source prior to invocation. (i.e. getOffset must immediately reflect the addition).


stop() Stops the execution of this query if it is running. This method blocks until the threads performing execution has stopped.
```

So whats the better way to restart query without stopping my spark streaming application

Comment: I added a reference example to my answer

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me.

Below is the scenario which I followed in spark 2.4.5 for left outer join and left join.Below process is pushing spark to read latest dimension data changes.

Process is for Stream Join with batch dimension (always update)

Step 1:-

Before starting Spark streaming job:- Make sure dimension batch data folder has only one file and the file should have at-least one record (for some reason placing empty file is not working)/

Step 2:- Start your streaming job and add a stream record in kafka stream

Step 3:- Overwrite dim data with values (the file should be same name don't change and the dimension folder should have only one file) Note:- don't use spark to write to this folder use Java or Scala filesystem.io to overwrite the file or bash delete the file and replace with new data file with same name.

Step 4:- In next batch spark is able to read updated dimension data while joining with kafka stream...

Sample Code:-

```
package com.databroccoli.streaming.streamjoinupdate

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType, TimestampType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object BroadCastStreamJoin3 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    @transient lazy val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("com.amazonaws").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("com.amazon.ws").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("io.netty").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val schemaUntyped1 = StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("id", StringType),
        StructField("customrid", StringType),
        StructField("customername", StringType),
        StructField("countrycode", StringType),
        StructField("timestamp_column_fin_1", TimestampType)
      ))

    val schemaUntyped2 = StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("id", StringType),
        StructField("countrycode", StringType),
        StructField("countryname", StringType),
        StructField("timestamp_column_fin_2", TimestampType)
      ))

    val factDf1 = spark.readStream
      .schema(schemaUntyped1)
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv("src/main/resources/broadcasttest/fact")


    val dimDf3 = spark.read
      .schema(schemaUntyped2)
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv("src/main/resources/broadcasttest/dimension")
      .withColumnRenamed("id", "id_2")
      .withColumnRenamed("countrycode", "countrycode_2")

    import spark.implicits._

    factDf1
      .join(
        dimDf3,
        $"countrycode_2" <=> $"countrycode",
        "inner"
      )
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear (the second piece of code doesn't use the df you want to persist so I am not sure how you intend to integrate them... I assume a join?

We had a similar issue (using Spark 2.1), and solved it by creating a custom implementation of Sink (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Sink.scala) where the data is loaded in addBatch. Since your setting indicate that you are only processing 1 file at a time and there is no watermarking, you can probably cram your logic into the addBatch method... though this is kind of hacky (our use case was slightly different I believe).

If spark 2.2 is an option, then you are in luck. Spark 2.2 adds the "run once" trigger that allows you to use the Spark Streaming API for batch jobs (which is essentially what you are trying to do). If you modify your write stream to use this new trigger, than the infinite loop might work (though I have never tried). You might be better off using an external scheduler to run the streaming job in batch mode. You can read more about the Run Once trigger here: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html

If you are using EMR, then Spark 2.2 isn't available yet... but I have heard it will be out in the next couple weeks (fingers crossed).

You can find some complete Sink implementation examples here: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-structured-streaming-ml/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/high-performance-spark-examples/structuredstreaming/CustomSink.scala

Comment: Jones:Sorry if my question is little confusing but the problem statement which im trying to solve is refreshing the cached dataframe without stopping the application ..when i looked into spark mailing list TDas suggested to restart streaming query for similar issue.So i want to know how to restart the streaming query

Comment: im using Spark 2.1 ,can you please let me know with sample how addbatch is useful to refresh cached dataframe without stopping streaming application

Comment: spark streaming isn't real "strearming", it is microbatching. When you use the writeStream method, you create a DataStreamWriter object. The 'format' method of DataStreamWriter is used to specify which output source to use. Implementing Sink allows you to create such a new output source. addBatch method takes a dataFrame, sparkSession, and options, and executes addBatch on every microbatch. This means code in addBatch executes every microbatch. The main downside is that all downstream transformation also has to take place in the  addBatch method. I will try to add a sample later.

Comment: Sorry I'm little confused should I add restart query in addbatch method ..trying to see how to refresh cached data frame in addbatch ?i understand your recommendation to write custom sink but how it's related to the problem which I'm trying to solve